# How Jesus Christ became prophet?

Tags: prophets, prophet-isa

It was always a question for me, How God chose prophets?
for example why Muhammad was chosen and not other prophet.
I have being told that God tests them before choosing them. Now it is a question for me
how Christ being chosen? He became prophet in the time he was born. How was he tested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allah is the Creator, He created them so He already knows them before they exist. Allah knows (as He is who created them) that they are good men and they are capable to fully conduct His message to people. Allah says in the "Mulk"(67) Chapter of the Holy Quran:

> {أَلَا يَعْلَمُ مَنْ خَلَقَ وَهُوَ اللَّطِيفُ الْخَبِيرُ(14)}

In this Allah asks (not really asking but for negation) if He wouldn't know whom He did created when He is the All-Subtle, the All-Aware!

So we learn from this Ayah that Allah knows people because He is already Who created them.

*And Allah knows best*.

Comment: I agree to Umer, and those good men are called `SOULS SELECTED ` by Allah (Subhanah-o-wa ta'ala)

Answer (score 0):

The names of all the Prophets were written on a wall in Jannah long before they were prophets, as Allah knows best. As for the tests of nabi Issa I'm not sure of any befor he was a Prophet only hardships and trials during his life.

Comment: You mean God chose some people(prophets) to be good and chose their destination before they were born?

Comment: @Reign Please provide reference for your answer (the names of all the Prophets were written on a wall in Jannah long before the were prophets)

Comment: So is there any algorithm in choosing prophets ? they were chosen before they born and before they do anything good, is this Adl ( عدل ) ?